# Keybinding Ctrl + Shift + C opens a new external terminal in vscode/codium on Linux, how do I change the shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, visual-studio-code, key-binding

In Visual Studio Code / Codium on Linux, the key binding `Ctrl+Shift+c` opens a new external terminal. This does not work together with vscodevim extension where I often need to copy to the system and always need to fall back to visual mode, then mark, then press the three buttons `"*y` to get it to the system clipboard.

How can I change or delete the keybinding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts [Ctrl+K Ctrl+S]` is where you find those settings.

[image]

You can type the key combinations into the search field on that page as well.

Looking up `Ctrl + Shift + C` shows a couple of commands, including **Open New External Terminal** which you are searching for. If you type `"Ctrl + Shift + C"`, you get the two that have just this shortcut.

[image]

To get rid of it completely, just click it and hit `Del` on your keyboard or use the context menu entry.

[image]

Or change it to another shortcut, it will tell you which shortcut you will overwrite then if the shortcut is already in use. In this case, a terminal can always be opened from the Linux desktop with `Ctrl+Shift+T` anyway. Thus, just delete it, you will not miss the shortcut in Codium.

Comment: I had a look at that before asking this. I could not find the shortcut there.

Comment: You can type the key combinations into the search field on that page as well. Looking up `Ctrl + Shift + C` does show me cuple commands, including **Open New External Terminal** which are you searching for.

Comment: Answer amended accordingly.

Comment: This does not open the terminal anymore. Yet, I still cannot use `Ctrl+Shift+C` to copy to the system terminal. I still have to use `"*y` in `v` mode instead. the answer is still right, of course. For how to use the system clipboard when using vscodevim extension, see the new Q/A [How to `Ctrl+C` copy to the system clipboard using vscodevim extension in vscode/codium without using the `v` mode's system clipboard register `"*y`?](https://superuser.com/questions/1723194/how-to-ctrlc-copy-to-the-system-clipboard-using-vscodevim-extension-in-vscode).