# How to `Ctrl+C` copy to the system clipboard using vscodevim extension in vscode/codium without using the `v` mode's system clipboard register `"*y`?

Tags: vim, copy-paste, visual-studio-code, key-binding, vscode-extensions

I have already changed the `Ctrl+Shift+C` keybinding so that I do not enter a terminal when I press it, see [Keybinding Ctrl + Shift + C opens a new external terminal in vscode/codium on Linux, how to change the shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/1722094/keybinding-ctrl-shift-c-opens-a-new-external-terminal-in-vscode-codium-on-li/1722104#1722104).

Yet, this `Ctrl+Shift+C` does not copy to the system keyboard. Therefore the next try, how can I get `Ctrl+C` back as a keybinding to copy to the system clipboard when using vscodevim extension in vscode/codium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just don't want vim to override the Ctrl key.  To do this for any vim key bindings, you can just go to the vim settings (search for `vim ctrl`) and disable `Vim: Use Ctrl Keys`

Answer (score 4):

The problem of how to copy to the system clipboard can be solved by changing or deleting the keybinding `Ctrl+C` for the command `extension.vim_ctrl+c` in the Keyboard shortcut settings
[image]

Search for `"Ctrl+C"` in the search field. You will find:

[image]

Or the full line:

[image]

You do not seem to need this shortcut since `Esc` does the same, see [Does using ctrl+c instead of esc to exit insert mode break anything in vi?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53633/does-using-ctrlc-instead-of-esc-to-exit-insert-mode-break-anything-in-vi).
After deleting that, you can use `Ctrl+C` to copy and then use vim's `Ctrl+Shift+V` to paste from system clipboard. Outside of vscode/codium, you can paste the system clipboard with the normal `Ctrl+V`.